# Zero inodes even after formatting hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, external-hard-drive, inode

I have an external 1Tb harddisk which due to some reason was showing following under `df -i`

```
Filesystem        Inodes   IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1              0       0         0     - /media/Transcend1T
```

But it has lots of free space remaining. So I took its backup and formatted it with disc utility in Ubuntu. But even after that Inodes still remain zero (it shows same output on `df -i`).

**Is this a problem? Can some filesystems always have zero inodes?**

Below is the output of `fdisk -l` on formatted disk.

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0ff10b79

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          64  1953520063   976760000    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Formatting screenshot. I first unmount the HDD and then click the `Format Volume` button shown. I have also clicked `Check filesystem` but it didn't fix the problem.
[image]

Comment: Exactly how are you formatting the disk? (i.e. screenshot of commands used, which software are you using with precise directions, etc) Perhaps you are making a minor mistake that we will notice.

Comment: @David added screenshot.

Comment: Does this method of adding a disk usually work for you, or is this the first time you have needed to?

Comment: @David yea, usually it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filesystem you are using as an example is FAT based; it does not have inodes.

> Is this a problem?

no

> Can some filesystems always have zero inodes?

yes (but never say never)

I checked a fat filesystem myself and df reports no inodes, though I have been successfully using it (and it is currently holding 10GB of data).